# Integral function

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I want to simulate the discharging of a battery.
I want to store on m.energy_remain[t] the energy remaining in that time instant (t). Untill now i am only able to compute the energy remaining in the final time, because integral() function compute all time-horizon (m.t).
How can i improve it to have also each time instant "i"?

```py
def _energy(M,t):
    return  m.power[1,t]+m.power[2,t]
m.energy = Integral(m.t, wrt=m.t,rule=_energy)

def _energy_consumed(M,t):
    return M.energy_remain[t] - 40000 + M.energy ==0
m.energy_remain_cons = Constraint(m.t,rule=_energy_consumed)
```